# responsive CSS - display:inline UL breaking into 2 lines, seems to have enough space

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm doing a responsive site and have navigation in the header using a UL set to display:inline. In a PC there will be a logo on the left and nav on the right. As screen size goes down, the nav will slide under the logo, both centred 768 to 400 wide and to the right below 400.

The UL is inside a container div and the problem is that as I resize my browser in the 460- 420 range (exact values seem to change with browser) my nav UL breaks onto 2 lines, even though there is space for it to stay on 1 line within its container div.

Thanks.

[image]

Codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRqbAO

HTML

```
   <header>
            <div class="hamburger">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src='design/testlogo.png' style='width:100%;max-width:338px;'>
            </div>


            <div class="shopping_nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class='fasize'><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i></li>
                    <li>Ireland<br>(Change)</li>
                    <li class='pipe_char'>|</li>
                    <li class='fasize'><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></li>
                    <li>Shipped<br>Globally</li>
                    <li class='pipe_char'>|</li>
                    <li class='fasize'><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i></li>
                    <li>2 items<br>&euro;21.45</li>
                    <li class='pipe_char'>|</li>
                    <li class='fasize'><i class="fa fa-search"></i></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


    </header>
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,300italic,300,100italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}

body {
  color: #444444;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Lato;
  margin:0px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    header{ background-color:black; height:150px; }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
    header{ background-color:black; height:134px; }
}



.hamburger  {padding:5px 8px;float:left;border:1px dashed white;}
.hamburger i {color:white;font-size: 40px;}



.logo {padding:5px;float:left;border:1px dashed white;}


.shopping_nav {
  float:right;
  padding:5px;
  color:white;
  border:1px dashed red;
  text-align:right;
}


.shopping_nav ul, .shopping_nav li {
    display:inline;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
}



.shopping_nav ul {
  border:1px solid green;
}



.shopping_nav .pipe_char {color:white;font-size: 26px;}
.shopping_nav .fasize {color:white;font-size: 24px;}


@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .shopping_nav ul, .shopping_nav li {
      display:inline;
      font-size: 13px;
      padding: 2px;
  }
  .shopping_nav .fasize {color:white;font-size: 20px;}
}

.shopping_nav li {display:inline-block;text-align:left;}




@media (max-width: 768px) {
.logo {max-width:338px;margin: 0 auto;float: none;}
.shopping_nav {max-width:380px;margin: 0 auto;float: none;}
}



@media (max-width: 400px) {
.logo {max-width:338px;float: right;}
.shopping_nav {padding:5px;max-width:380px;float: right;}
}



@media (max-width: 460px) {
  .logo {width:250px;}
}


@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .hamburger  {display:none;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `display: inline` from `.shopping_nav ul`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGPRQQ

Comment: Thanks - that seems to fix it on Win 10/Firefox. However on FF/Ubuntu the problem still exists from 768 to 400 px wide, but have just checked am on an old version, will upgrade. Can I ask  why display: inline was causing th problem, I thought that was the standard way to use ULs for navigation?

Comment: yes, but the inline setting (or inline-block) should be applied to the `li` elements, not to the `ul`.

Comment: OK, thanks. I upgraded my FF to latest version, problem still exists.

Comment: I fixed it on FF on Ubuntu, it seems the Font Awesome icons were being rendered a tiny bit bigger than on my PC or Mac

Answer (score 0):

You have to set "text-align: center" for mobile view. Currently it is using "text-align: right"

Code here: http://codeamaze.com/code-beautifier/html-beautifier/ZI3qBj7YS6A=

Output: Paste the code here: http://codeamaze.com/web-viewer/html-viewer

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will  try that. in the viewer, I cannot resize below 415, will try it out later when i get to work.

Comment: Makes no difference - it appears to work in your link above, but only because the Font Awesome icons are missing - once I put those back in again the issue re-appeared